# Why is my battery not charging?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery

I have my battery at 95% and it's not charging while plugged in.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Do you know if it might be a setting somewhere?

Comment: Not charging to 100% is goodness, if you commonly use the unit plugged in.  The battery lasts a lot longer (though only charging to 60% is closer to optimal for battery life).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I get this occasionally, it is nothing to be worried about.

It depends on the make, model and version of your laptop. Some power circuits are different and do weird things.

My laptop usually goes to 100%, then 3 times a week, it discharges 5% and does what yours is, then usually goes back to 100% after a few hours.

As long as it is working, I would not be worried.

Comment: To add to this: It makes no sense to re-charge the battery if it's close to 100 % full. You always have a little self-discharge and constantly cycling the battery between discharging and charging is nonsense. That's why the electronics on most laptops/batteries prevent charging before it reaches a certain threshold which is somewhat below 100 %.

Answer (score 3):

Battery level is not an exact science.  Windows makes a good guess and only reports what the hardware is doing.  I'm guessing your battery is actually full and it has made the choice to not charge.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after buying a new laptop battery.  I found a solution that seems to have worked [here](http://www.asktheadmin.com/2008/06/plugged-in-not-charging-0-remaining.html).
The summary is:
 - Shut down the laptop
 - Unplug the power cord
 - Remove the battery
 - Hold down the power button for 10 secs "to discharge connectors"(whatever that means)
 - Re-insert the battery
 - Plug the power cord back in and turn on the laptop

Answer (score 1):

Try calibrating your battery. Charge it to the max, use it without power until it completely dies, then fully charge it again.

Apple's [description](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490) on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the Advanced Battery Charge Configuration setting in the BIOS from "custom" to "adaptive":

1. Restart the computer
2. When the logo shows up, press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or whatever key to enter boot, depending on the device... mine is <kbd>F2</kbd>)
3. Go to the "Advanced" tab
4. Change **Advanced Battery Charge Configuration** from **[Custom]** to **[Adaptive]**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Right click the Battery Status in the system tray(right bottom of the desktop)

2) Select **"Power Options"**

3) Click on **"Longevity Mode"** tab and select the "Disable" radio button".

The next time you charge your laptop it has to charge upto 100%

Comment: This is not a Windows option, it was added by a third-party software.

Answer (score -2):

This is the way it works:

1. When you power on your laptop, if your battery is above 95%. you will get the message "plugged but not charging"
2. When you power on your laptop, if your battery is under 95%, you will see the message "Plugged and charging" until the battery charge reaches 100% (not 95%).  That's why sometimes, even if you see that your battery is at 97% and charging also, that means before starting your laptop, the battery was under 95% and reaches 97% since then.

Here are the steps to fix the problem:

1. Click Start and type device in the search field, then select Device Manager.
2. Expand the Batteries category.
3. Under the Batteries category, right-click the Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery listing, and select `Uninstall`.
   **WARNING : Do not remove the Microsoft AC Adapter driver or any other ACPI compliant driver.**
4. On the Device Manager taskbar, click Scan for hardware changes.
   Alternately, select Action > Scan for hardware changes.